# Mouse disappears while using Barrier

Tags: software-installation, mouse, 22.04

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop and Windows 10 on my computer and I've been trying to set up mouse and keyboard share with Barrier (my Windows PC as a server and my Ubuntu laptop as a Client). The connection works fine, but the mouse becomes invisible when I enter the Ubuntu screen (I'm sure it works cause I can click and use the mouse but I can't see it). Is this a known issue and if yes, does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's caused by wayland, you need change to XORG.

[How to enable/disable wayland ou ubuntu 22.04](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes and thank you. Both you and Mohammad Suheb are amazing people! Worked for me!!

Answer (score 8):

1. Open a terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
   ```
2. Uncomment this:

   ```
   #WaylandEnable=false
   ```
3. Restart.

This disables your gestures but your barrier cursor works very well.

You can revert this action just by commenting:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and run:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

Comment: This question was already answered, thank you though,

Comment: This is actually a better answer since it lists out all the steps instead of just providing a link! Thank you :)

Comment: This worked very well for me too, except for one little detail. On Debian 11 bullseye Wayland needed to be disabled in /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf

Comment: you didnt say why they should do this thing.  it is not a fix its a workaround and there will be other consequences from changing the underlying server concept,
you just needed to say its not supported in wayland

Answer (score 4):

This Q&A helped me solve the 'invisible mouse' issue a few months ago (solution: disable use of Wayland) however, recently I ran into the issue again but this time Wayland was already disabled.

So, for those who happen to come across this Q&A and find the 'disable use of Wayland' solution does not fix their issue, perhaps this may be of some help ...

---

Turns out there's an(other) issue having to do with Barrier *server* 2.4.0 running under a Windows OS with a display scaling > 100% ...

- **Barrier version:** 2.4.0
- **Barrier *server* OS:** Windows
- **Windows display scaling factor:** > 100% (eg, Windows defaults to a scaling factor of 150% for 4K monitors)
- **Issue:** Barrier miscalculates the 'edge of the screen' and in doing so leaves an invisible cursor locked onto the client.
- **Fix #1:** reduce Windows scaling (back) to 100%; downside, many apps may now be too small to view/read
- **Fix #2:** downgrade to Barrier 2.3.4; this version has no problems dealing with scaling > 100% when the Barrier *server* OS is Windows; appears to have no issues working with a Barrier *client* that's running Barrier 2.4.0

**NOTES:**

- see [Barrier: Issue # 1713 - Cursor disappears on server and client](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/1713) for more details
- the scaling issue doesn't appear to affect Barrier servers running non-Windows OSs (eg, linux + 4K monitor); not sure if the issue affects Barrier clients running Windows OS

**My current (working) setup:**

- Wayland disabled on all linux hosts running Barrier
- my Windows host (Barrier *server*) is running Barrier 2.3.4 (display scaling == 150%)
- all linux hosts (Barrier *server* or *client*) are running Barrier 2.4.0
- I don't have any Windows hosts configured as a Barrier *client*